# Why can't cabal haddock find lens?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haddock

I've got a project where I'm trying out the [lens](http://lens.github.com/) library.  I'm trying to generate haddock docs so I can see the functions produced by the `makeClassy` `TemplateHaskell` function. `cabal build` works fine, but `cabal haddock` fails with

```
$ cabal haddock
Running Haddock for myproject-0.0.1...
Warning: The documentation for the following packages are not installed. No
links will be generated to these packages: rts-1.0
Preprocessing library myproject-0.0.1...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id lens-3.7.1-a40583cdc124338f52ab40ebbf747e8f
    (use -v for more information)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `cabal haddock -v` give more information? Which package id does `ghc-pkg describe lens` report?

Comment: @DanielFischer `cabal haddock -v` doesn't give any more information, just dumps the `haddock` command it runs.  I running that directly and increasing the verbosity, but it didn't offer any additional information.  `ghc-pkg describe lens` reports `name: lens
version: 3.7.1
id: lens-3.7.1-a40583cdc124338f52ab40ebbf747e8f
license: BSD3`

Comment: Pity. Normally something like `cannot satisfy -package-id lens-3.7.1-a40583cdc124338f52ab40ebbf747e8f` indicates a missing or broken dependency. But if `cabal build` works, that doesn't seem to be the case. Nevertheless, checking for broken packages with `ghc-pkg check` or `ghc -v` is never a bad idea. You can try whether `cabal install` works, though I don't know why it should pass different options to haddock.